# Sonata Exception get too many admin registered

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I get the message:

> Unable to found a valid admin for the class: Aman\VarshneyBundle\Entity\ArticleTable, get too many admin registered: sonata.admin.appsreview,sonata.admin.review,sonata.admin.article

I am not able to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you have to specify "admin_code" option in your field definition

in your admin class while building your form

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('user', 'entity', array(), array(
        'admin_code' => 'your.user.admin.service'

    ));
}
```

It only happens when you have multiple admin classes for the same entity.

Comment: create and edit are using the same form. Once you have an error in your form configuration you will have it on both create and edit.

Comment: It worked for me. Just make sure its a 4th argument for the field.

Comment: Caution: For the listmapper and showmapper you have to add it to the third parameter array, how confusing

Comment: Do not forget to add the classname in the first array():
``$formMapper->add('user', 'entity', array(
        'class' => YourEntity::class
        ), array(
        'admin_code' => 'your.user.admin.service'
    ));``

Answer (score 3):

I will put code with the use for the 'configureListFields' method, if it's  usefull for someone.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
$listMapper
    ->add('filename', null, array('admin_code' => 'your.file.admin.service', 'label' => 'File Name'))
    ->add('parent', 'sonata_type_list', array('admin_code' => 'your.file.admin.service', 'label' => 'Parent File'))
    ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
        'label' => 'Actions',
        'actions' => array(
            'download' => array(
                'template' => 'FileAdminBundle:File:list__action_download.html.twig'
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

As we see, if we have multiple fields, we must put the 'admin_code' in all of them, excepts the actions (if we have it).

Hope it helps.